# Design problems. Throwing checked Exceptions for illegal arguments

Tags: java

I have a problem where I have to rely on throwing exceptions due to invalid arguments in a builder class, and I want to see if there is a better way. Here is my situation:

I am making a sort of Command framework where a single command is defined by a class implementing a Command interface that defines a single method

```
boolean execute(Object... args);
```

The execute method accepts the arguments necessary to execute the command, and the arguments will be different for every command. To avoid having to check every argument type in a mess of instanceof and if-else trees, I made a complex Annotation structure that each Command class should define called CommandInfo. This annotation defines all of the arguments along with their expected class type, and I am making it so that the arguments  provided to the execute method will be guaranteed to be the correct based entirely on the CommandInfo annotation. So to accomplish this, I changed the varArgs parameter of the command arguments to a new type called Arguments. This Arguments class utilizes the builder pattern so that there is a private constructor and the only way to get an instance of the class is to call the builders 'build' method. This Builder takes an instance to the Command the arguments will be for, and the array of string arguments to be converted. The build method is what makes all of the validation checks and conversions of the provided arguments based on the commands CommandInfo annotation.

Now all this works great, but what I am having problems with is handling when an invalid set of arguments is given. Normally, a builder class will throw IllegalStateException when it was not provided with the correct variables, but that is a runtime exception and is usually used for programming errors. In my case, it will be very common to give an invalid set of arguments, so a checked exception would make more sense. It is important that I fail silently while notifying the human that provided the invalid set of arguments.

So what would be my best option here? should I subclass a new checked exception to throw when the provided arguments were invalid? I don't really want to rely on throwing exceptions, but since I am using the builder pattern, the build method must return an instance to the Arguments class. So throwing exceptions is the only way to stop from actually building the Arguments instance. Also, I don't want to return null because I want to avoid NPE's

Comment: Is it not possible to overload `execute()` to avoid this situation in the first place?

Comment: No because the Command interface is provided by an API, and that API is what validates the command arguments. each Command subclass is registered through the API, and there is no way for the API to execute a subclass's overloaded method.

Comment: Hmmm, that's unfortunate... Because it seems you expect the client to be able to recover from this and you can't return a `null` object, a checked exception sounds like it would work. Another possibility is returning a Null Object, but I'm guessing that that's not going to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked on a project that had some similar concerns.  We avoided the use of Exceptions for signalling validation errors by wrapping all returns (even void) in an ExResult.  When commands were returned, we would check the results' success/failure status before attempting to access the return data.  This also allows you to attach additional information to the result object.

```
ExResult<Boolean> result = command.execute()
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    Boolean resultData = result.getData();
} else {
    //handle issue
    result.getReason();
}
```

Initially, we had issues of growing large conditional trees when multiple commands had to be executed sequentially and depended on previous results.  We overcame the issue by attaching the previous result (if any) to the next command so that the next command could determine if it wanted to continue, as well as attach its own result to the result object.

Comment: Oh, that reminds me JavaScript Promises so much... Btw this is a hint for digging other architectural patterns.

Comment: This got me thinking and I ended up doing something pretty similar. thanks!